# Magento how to add simple product to shoping cart

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7

Let say I have a simple product id and I want to add it to shopping cart.
I can add it with

`cart->addProduct($product, array('qty'=>1));`

But the problem is its  attributes , I want to add them also for example the size and color of the product.

Comment: `But the problem is its attributes` - it is attribute or custom options?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the attributes information in the cart. 
In app/design/frontend/default/your-theme/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml